# When I add an image to a button, the attribute “NSLineBreakByWordWrapping” of the button doesn't work

Tags: ios, uibutton

As the title shows,the button contains both an image and so many words, the image is on the left of the words. when I don't add an image to a button,the attribute works.But when I add it,the attribute doesn't work.How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Because, “NSLineBreakByWordWrapping” works for its name;line will break by word wrapping but not image wrapping.

Comment: Sorry, I described it wrong.Not the label but the button?And the the button contains both image and text.As the question shows again.

Answer (score 0):

```
NIAttributedLabel *label = [[NIAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 0)];
[label setLineHeight:20];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[label insertImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] atIndex:0];
[label sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```